# How can I have multiple authentication methods with only one having to succeed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Unfortunately I can't find anything that would help me in this matter.

Normally API uses OIDC to handle authentication so we have ordinary `.AddAuthentication.AddJwtBearer` used as default. That works fine, BUT we also need to be able to have another way of authentication that would provide user identity, because token is not always available. Let's say it would be some ApiKey with dictionary of users for given ApiKey.

Still, I would like JWT Token to have priority over this another layer, because it's just stronger kind of authentication. So it would be something like that:

1. We receive request
2. If we see Authorization header then it means that request provides token - we want to validate that token, if it's invalid - we want 401 because something is not right.
3. If there is no Authorization header in HttpRequest, but we have ApiKey header - we want to omit validating tokens completely and try to check that ApiKey. If it's valid we want to set HttpContext.User from there and tell that entire authentication went fine and our controllers can use HttpContext.User normally.

Currently we have multiple controller endpoints that support token OR ApiKey (different attribute) scenario, but when number of controllers and endpoints raises it may be pretty painful to duplicate everything.

I tried to attach to some `JwtBearerEvents` and check headers there so I can finish authentication manually if I see that we don't have token available, for example:

```
OnMessageReceived = async context =>
{
    if (!context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization") 
        && context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("ApiKey"))
    {
         // some logic to check that ApiKey
         context.Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(
             new Claim[]
             {
                 new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "ApiKeyUser")
             }));
         context.Success();
    }
    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Unfortunately middleware insists on checking token anyway and returning 401, so that's most probably not valid approach to resolve that problem.

Answer (score 5):

I found a way, so I will leave that here. You can just use `AddPolicyScheme` to add selector that will use different handlers by calling them by name.

For example:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = smartAuthenticationScheme; // just some string
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = smartAuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultScheme = smartAuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddPolicyScheme(smartAuthenticationScheme, "Token / Custom", options =>
        {
            options.ForwardDefaultSelector = context =>
            {
                var header = (string)context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

                if (header == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(header))
                    return undefinedAuthenticationScheme;

                if (header.StartsWith("Bearer"))
                    return bearerAuthenticationScheme; // it's just JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
                if (header.StartsWith("Custom"))
                    return customAuthenticationScheme;

                return undefinedAuthenticationScheme;
            };
        })
        .AddJwt(bearerAuthenticationScheme, configuration)
        .AddCustom(customAuthenticationScheme)
        .AddUndefined(undefinedAuthenticationScheme);
```

And this way our middleware will look at content of Authorization header and call AuthenticationHandler that is registered under given name. UndefinedHandler exist only to serve 401 response when content of Authorization header matches neither Jwt nor Custom AuthorizationHandler.

Comment: Does AddUndefined register a predefined authentication scheme or does it register a custom authentication handler?